# Which (co)homology theories have (co)chain complexes, spectrum edition?

Tags: algebraic-topology, homological-algebra, stable-homotopy-theory, triangulated-categories, spectra

What homological functors $\mathbf{Sp}\rightarrow\mathbf{Ab}$ arise in the form $H_0\circ T$, for $T:\mathbf{Sp}\rightarrow D(\mathbf{Ab})$ a triangulated functor, and dually for cohomological functors $\mathbf{Sp}^{\mathrm{op}}\rightarrow\mathbf{Ab}$? What if I replace $\mathbf{Sp}$ with a derived category? Here, $D(\mathbf{Ab})$ is the derived category of unbounded complexes of Abelian groups, $\mathbf{Sp}$ the triangulated category of spectra, and $H_0:D(\mathbf{Ab})\rightarrow\mathbf{Ab}$ the usual homology functor.

Phrased less formally, what (co)homology theories of spectra can be presented by a natural complex(?) of $D(\mathbf{Ab})$? For context, I am trying to understand triangulated/derived category formalism, and this seems an important baseline to establish.

Ordinary homology with $A$ coefficients can be presented this way by letting $TX$ be the limit $\varinjlim C_\bullet\left(X_n;A\right)$ of the cellular complexes of the spaces $X_n$ comprising the spectrum $X$. On the other hand, a proposition on page 35 of [a set of notes by Krause](http://homepages.math.uic.edu/%7Ebshipley/krause.chicago.pdf) seems to imply one cannot factor $\pi^S_0$ through $H_0$. My question seems closely related to [this one](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1870317/whats-a-cohomology-thats-not-defined-from-a-cochain-complex), based on which it seems plausible to guess the answer is that ordinary (co)homology is the only answer up to translation and direct sum (product?).

As a related-but-not-quite-the-same question, I was trying the following approach before the above discouraged me from working out more details. Consider a cohomology theory $E^*$ of pointed CW complexes represented by an $\Omega$-spectrum $\left(E_n\right)$. One has a sequence of pointed spaces

$$ \cdots\rightarrow \mathcal{P}E_{n-1} \rightarrow \mathcal{P}E_n \rightarrow \mathcal{P}E_{n+1} \rightarrow \cdots $$

given by stringing together the path space fibrations $\Omega E_n\rightarrow\mathcal{P}E_n\rightarrow E_n$ of the spaces $E_n$. It seems with a little care one should be able to describe a cochain complex from this sort of thing, closely-related enough to path space fibrations to have meaningful cohomology. (One has to be more careful than "take homotopy classes of maps" since $\mathcal{P}E_n$ is contractible.) Does this sort of thing lead anywhere? If so, the only reasonable places I could see this ending up are a tautology or the vicinity of an Atiyah-Hirzebruch spectral sequence.

I am a number theory student, so I apologize if some technical details regarding algebraic topology are a little vague or not quite correct.

Comment: I think you could post this on math overflow, I think people will know some examples and nonexamples. For example, I think I've seen claimed that bordism theories don't generally come from chain complexes (of groups).