# Given spectrum and space $X$ construct chain complex that computes the cohomology

Tags: algebraic-topology, homology-cohomology, homotopy-theory, stable-homotopy-theory

Suppose we are given a spectrum,  as explained in https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spectrum_(topology) this means we are given a collection of CW complexes $\{E_k\}_{k\in \mathbb N}$  and maps $i_k:\Sigma E_k \to E_{k+1}$ inducing h-equivalences.

Now suppose we are given $X^n$ a finite CW complex of dimension $n$.

The spectrum defines a generalized cohomology theory where the cohomology in degree $d$ of a topological space $X$ is given by $$\mathcal E^d(X) = \lim_{l\to +\infty}[X_+, \Omega^l E_{d+l}]_0 $$
which I guess (?) should be also equal to $\mathcal E^d(X) = [X_+, \Omega^L E_{n+L}]_0 $ for some $L$ large enough.

> Question: can we cook up, in general, a (co)chain complex depending on $X$ and on the spectrum $(C(X, \{E_k\}_k), d)$ which computes the cohomology?

This curiosity is motivated by the fact that  this is possible for singular cohomology, so I was wondering if we can do it for any generalized cohomology theory.

Comment: My impression is that this should not be possible (in a useful way) unless the spectrum is more or less an Eilenberg-MacLane spectrum but I'm not aware of a precise theorem along these lines. For example I don't believe this is possible for K-theory. Of course there is a useless way, you can take the cohomology as the complex with zero differential.

Comment: Ah, here is a precise statement: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1870317/whats-a-cohomology-thats-not-defined-from-a-cochain-complex

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What's a cohomology that's not defined from a cochain complex?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1870317/whats-a-cohomology-thats-not-defined-from-a-cochain-complex)